# Почему странно работает OR? MySql

Tags: mysql

Запрос составлен следующим образом:

```
command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student_name AS 'Имя студента', date_birth AS 'Дата рождения', email AS 'E-mail', university_name AS 'Название университета', teacher_name AS 'Имя преподователя', experiment_name AS 'Название эксперимента',  tent_color AS 'Цвет палатки', points AS 'Баллы' FROM `student`, `teacher`, `tent`, `experiment`, `university` WHERE teacher.id_teacher = student.id_teacher AND tent.id_tent = student.id_tent AND experiment.id_experiment = student.id_experiment AND university.id_university = student.id_university AND student_name LIKE @word OR date_birth LIKE @word OR email LIKE @word OR university_name LIKE @word OR teacher_name LIKE @word OR experiment_name LIKE @word OR tent_color LIKE @word or points LIKE @word ORDER BY student_name ASC", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@word", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
```

Почему такой вывод и как это исправить? Предполагалось сделать фильтрацию... Причём, если вводить имя, то всё нормально
[image: mysql]

Answer (score 0):

Въехал.

```html
command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student_name AS 'Имя студента', date_birth AS 'Дата рождения', email AS 'E-mail', university_name AS 'Название университета', teacher_name AS 'Имя преподователя', experiment_name AS 'Название эксперимента',  tent_color AS 'Цвет палатки', points AS 'Баллы' FROM `student`, `teacher`, `tent`, `experiment`, `university` WHERE teacher.id_teacher = student.id_teacher AND tent.id_tent = student.id_tent AND experiment.id_experiment = student.id_experiment AND university.id_university = student.id_university AND student_name LIKE @word OR date_birth LIKE @word OR email LIKE @word OR university_name LIKE @word OR teacher_name LIKE @word OR experiment_name LIKE @word OR tent_color LIKE @word or points LIKE @word ORDER BY student_name ASC", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@word", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
```